# Find a row with max sum of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I create the DataFrame with code

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ["id_1",6,7,9],
    ["id_2",9,7,1],
    ["id_3",6,7,10],
    ["id_4",9,5,10]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Student Id', 'Math', 'Physical', 'Chemistry'])
```

How we can find a row with max(Math + Physical + Chemistry), result = id_4

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you want the output... maybe something like: `df.loc[df.sum(1).idxmax()]` ? What if there's more than one identical max value?

Comment: `df[['Math', 'Physical', 'Chemistry']].sum(1).idxmax()`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Student Id column as index and then calculate the max sum.

```py
df = df.set_index('Student Id')
print(df.sum(axis=1).idxmax())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df=df.loc[df[['Math', 'Physical', 'Chemistry']].sum(1).idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

df.loc[df[['Math', 'Physical', 'Chemistry']].sum(axis = 1).idxmax(), 'Student Id']